Apache Camel: The mail message does not have any recipients set
camel-context.xml
<route id="mail-route-imap" autoStartup="true">
    <!-- Trigger the route using a timer -->
    <from uri="timer://loadEmailParams?period=10000" />

    <!-- Process the bean to fetch IMAP URL and Port -->
    <process ref="emailConfigProcessor" />

    <!-- Log the dynamic properties -->
    <log message="Fetching from IMAP URL: ${exchangeProperty.imapUrl}, Port: ${exchangeProperty.imapPort}" />

    <!-- Fetch emails dynamically using toD for IMAP -->
    <toD uri="imaps://${exchangeProperty.imapUrl}:${exchangeProperty.imapPort}?authenticator=#exchangeAuthenticator&amp;mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms=XOAUTH2&amp;searchTerm=#customSearchTerm" />

    <!-- Log the successful fetching of emails -->
    <log message="Fetched emails from ${exchangeProperty.imapUrl}" />
</route>

Processor:
@Component
public class EmailConfigProcessor implements Processor {

    @Autowired
    private EmailConfigBean emailConfigBean;

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.setProperty("imapUrl", emailConfigBean.getImapUrl());
        exchange.setProperty("imapPort", emailConfigBean.getImapPort());
    }
}

EmailConfigBean
@Component("emailConfigBean")
public class EmailConfigBean {
    public String getImapUrl() {
        return "myoutlook.com";  // Example IMAP URL
    }

    public String getImapPort() {
        return "my-imap-port";  // Example IMAP Port
    }
}

Error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The mail message does not have any recipients set.
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailBinding.populateMailMessage(MailBinding.java:157)

Alternative approach tried with :
<route id="mail-route-imap" autoStartup="true">
    <!-- Set properties for IMAP URL and port from EmailConfigBean -->
    <process ref="emailConfigProcessor" />

    <!-- Log the properties for debugging -->
    <log message="IMAP URL: ${exchangeProperty.imapUrl}, IMAP Port: ${exchangeProperty.imapPort}" />

    <!-- Dynamically resolve the IMAP endpoint -->
    <toD
        uri="imaps://${exchangeProperty.imapUrl}:${exchangeProperty.imapPort}?authenticator=#exchangeAuthenticator&amp;mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms=XOAUTH2&amp;searchTerm=#customSearchTerm" />
</route>


Are you sure, the issue is with the IMAP properties? The null pointer exception looks more like the missing bean #exchangeAuthenticator.

@Raphi1 You are right! Let me rephrase the question . I have already fixed the original issue for which I came to SO.

@Raphi1 Rephrased. I get an issue as "The mail message does not have any recipients set." This is an IMAP route where I am supposed to read emails from a mailbox.

Is your process method of your processor being called? You can set a breakpoint there. Is the emailConfigBean returning the correct values?

yep it is ! I already checked that! The problem started when I made the changes in camel-context.xml for IMAP

In particulaar, the problem started when I made the changes in camel-context.xml for IMAP to fetch imap url and port dynamically through ''

Is your log endpoint printing the correct values of the properties?

The particular error is thrown here https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/10d8e3b1b3392eb8dfc4919effce5b427f45fdbb/components/camel-mail/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/mail/MailBinding.java#L157
so it looks like, the message doesn't have any recipients, like the error is indicating.

right, but this is an IMAP route so it is not intended to have a 'to'. But rather a mailbox to which the route is listening to. It worked fine for:
. this fails when the route is updated as


Dear @Raphi1, I have posted a fresh question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79029647/apache-camelemail-msal4j-acquiretokenbyclientcredentialsupplier-failed .
Please lemme know if you have come across something similar.

You can not use the <from uri="timer..." when you want to consume a mailbox. As the mail component supports both consumer (from) and producer (to), it behaves completely different. While the consumer will read emails from a mailbox, the producer will send emails. Therefore it complains about the missing recipient, when used in a to endpoint.
There are several mechanisms to schedule the consumer (to actually get rid of the "trigger" timer). Nevertheless, this will not help you with your dynamic url, since you would need to trigger the processor first.
It depends of your actual setup how you can proceed now. If you, for example have a fixed list of hosts and ports, you could set up a Map or a List, populate them with the connection data and just create multiple routes via a for-loop. As I never used the xml DSL, only Java DSL, I'm not sure, if this can be achieved with xml.
Here is an example for the java dsl:
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    List<String> connections = List.of("myoutlook.com:my-port");

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
                for (String connection: connections) {
                    from("imaps://" + connection + "?authenticator=#exchangeAuthenticator&amp;mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms=XOAUTH2&amp;searchTerm=#customSearchTerm&delay=10000")
                    .routeId("mail-route-imap")
                    .log("Fetched emails from " + connection);
                }
        }
}

You could also try to use PropertyPlaceholders. Then your route could look like this:
camel-context.xml
<route id="mail-route-imap" autoStartup="true">
    <!-- Trigger the route using a timer -->
    <from uri="imaps://{{imapUrl}}:{{imapPort}}?authenticator=#exchangeAuthenticator&amp;mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms=XOAUTH2&amp;searchTerm=#customSearchTerm&amp;delay=10000" />
    <!-- Log the successful fetching of emails -->
    <log message="Fetched emails from {{imapUrl}}:{{imapPort}}" />
</route>

application.properties
imapUrl=myoutlook.com
imapPort=my-port

UPDATE
What you want, you can achieve with the Content Enricher, specifically with the pollEnrich endpoint. I will give the example as Java DSL, but it's also possible with xml dsl. You should be able to easily convert it to xml, but I'm not 100% sure about the syntax...
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer://loadEmailParams?period=10000")
        .routeId("mail-route-imap")
        .to("sql:SELECT imapUrl, imapPort FROM connection_parameters") // get the connection parameters from the database, returns a list of Maps -> <FieldName, FieldValue>
        .split(body()) // split the records, aka process the following lines for every database record
            .pollEnrich("imaps://${body.imapUrl}:${body.imapPort}?authenticator=#exchangeAuthenticator&amp;mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms=XOAUTH2&amp;searchTerm=#customSearchTerm", new ExampleAggregationStrategy())
            .process(exchange -> {
                // do something with your emails
                // of course, you can use a real Processor here, not a lambda expression
                // the imap connection information are not available here anymore
            })
        .end();
    }
}

public class ExampleAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        Map<String, Object> databaseRecord = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(Map.class);
        System.out.println("Fetched emails from " + databaseRecord.get("imapUrl").toString() + ":" + databaseRecord.get("imapPort").toString());
        return newExchange;
    }
}

The ExampleAggregationStrategy prints out the current connection parameters and then returns the newExchange (which is just result of the pollEnrich endpoint), which is your emails here.
You can also check the manual https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/eips/pollEnrich-eip.html and there are also examples with xml.

Hi @Raphi1, Thanks for your detailed answer. With properties as an approach it works as a charm. I had already tried that before. The challenge is I need to pick up the imapUrl and imapPort from DB since they can be changed and my camel route should be able to read them without a downtime of the camel app.I tried using the '' tag (updated in my answer as an alternative approach) but the problem persists because of the reason you mentioned about the mail component's intrinsic support for both 'producer' and 'consumer'. Would having a Java DSL help?

@raikumardipak I have updated my answer. Please check, if this helps now

somehow the  emailConfigProcessor in my XML based declaration is not being called everytime but only once? Could there be anything I am doing wrong? I am not getting the updated value of IMAP URL/PORT dyncamically from the exchange property?

How does your actual emailConfigProcessor look like? As you mentioned you're reading the values from the database, you're probably not using the bean with the static values, right? Please provide the relevant code.

I raised a question for the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79044095/apache-camel-pollenrich-tag-causing-the-timer-uri-to-fail-in-camel-xml-context.
The problem lies in the  tag but I am not sure why

Thanks to @Raphi1's answer I could come up with the below answer. But the use of pollEnrich breaks the timer. Refer this question Apache Camel <pollEnrich> tag causing the timer uri to fail in camel xml context
<route id="route-imap" autoStartup="true">
    <!-- Input to trigger the route -->
    <from uri="timer://loadEmails?period=100" />
    <process ref="emailConfigProcessor" />
    <!-- Log the properties for debugging -->
    <log
        message="IMAP URL: ${exchangeProperty.imapUrl}, IMAP Port: ${exchangeProperty.imapPort}" />
    <!-- Poll from IMAP dynamically using pollEnrich -->
    <pollEnrich timeout="5000">
        <simple>imaps://${exchangeProperty.imapUrl}:${exchangeProperty.imapPort}?authenticator=#exchangeAuthenticator&amp;mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms=XOAUTH2&amp;searchTerm=#mySearch</simple>
    </pollEnrich>
    <!-- Ensure MIME type conversion -->
    <convertBodyTo type="javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage" />
    <!-- Log all headers for debugging -->
    <log message="All Headers: ${headers}" />
    <!-- Further processing after email retrieval -->
    <to uri="direct:emailProcessChain" />
</route>

