Apache Camel <pollEnrich> tag causing the timer uri to fail in camel xml context
In my camel-context.xml definition below, the loadEmails uri triggers
exactly after every 5 seconds and the emailConfigProcessor also loads after every 5 seconds with the values fetched from the autowired emailConfigBean.
But when I enable the <pollEnrich> tag the timer fails to trigger periodically. I duly verified this by commenting and un-commenting the <pollEnrich>. When I commented out the <pollEnrich> all logs from the emailConfigProcessor bean and the timer are getting printed periodically.
camel-context.xml
<route id="mail-route-imap" autoStartup="true">
            <!-- Input to trigger the route -->
            <from uri="timer://loadEmails?period=5000&amp;fixedRate=false" />
            <log message="Timer triggered!" />
            <!-- Log when the timer triggers -->
            <log message="Timer triggered, calling emailConfigProcessor..." />
            <process ref="emailConfigProcessor" />
            <log message="IMAP URL: ${exchangeProperty.imapUrl}, IMAP Port: ${exchangeProperty.imapPort}" />
            <!-- Poll from IMAP dynamically using pollEnrich --> 
            <pollEnrich timeout="10000000"> 
            <simple>imaps://${exchangeProperty.imapUrl}:${exchangeProperty.imapPort}?authenticator=#exchangeAuthenticator&amp;debugMode=true&amp;delete=false&amp;unseen=true&amp;delay=10000&amp;mail.imaps.proxy.host={{proxyHost}}&amp;mail.imaps.proxy.port={{proxyPort}}&amp;mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms=XOAUTH2&amp;searchTerm=#customSearchTerm</simple> 
            </pollEnrich>
            <log message="Route 'mail-route-imap' registered successfully." />
</route>

EmailConfigProcessor.java
public class EmailConfigProcessor implements Processor {
    @Autowired
    private EmailConfigBean emailConfigBean;

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("@#E#@@# EmailConfigProcessor ..... {} ", new Date());
        exchange.setProperty("imapUrl", emailConfigBean.getImapUrl()); //this is fetched clean and logged
        exchange.setProperty("imapPort", emailConfigBean.getImapPort()); //this is fetched clean and logged
    }
}

UPDATE
I changed the timeout to 10 seconds for pollEnrich and 1 second for the timeras below and the Email Configurations are picked. But every mail chain reply gives an error as FolderClosedException
org.apache.camel.spi.CamelLogger: Error occurred: Error during type conversion from type: javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart to the required type: org.apache.camel.StreamCache with value javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@49f542c2 due to org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart to the required type: org.apache.camel.StreamCache with value javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@49f542c2 due to javax.mail.FolderClosedException: null

This question is closely related with another attempt at solving this problem initially Apache Camel: The mail message does not have any recipients set

What happens, if you lower the timeout of the pollEnrich? Switching from pollEnrich to enrich will not work, as with enrich the endpoint is used as a destination/consumer while pollEnrich will treat it as a source/producer.

Yes, reducing the timeout works @Raphi1. I kept the   to 10 seconds and changed the timer period to 1 second. .
I see that even if I am rapidly changing the properties of IMAP URL/PORT in my DB it is being picked up by the 'exchangeProperty' through the 'emailConfigProcessor'. Although I am not sure if the design I am building of dynamically picking up IMAP/SMTP URL/PORT details in my camel route from a DB/Kafka is a foolproof one.(?)

@Raphi1, updated the steps taken with the timeout and the subsequent new error of 'javax.mail.FolderClosedException: null' on a reply chain, i.e. when the same mail is sent as a reply to the IMAP route. I was looking to your answer in the other post linked with this where you have mentioned the use of an 'AggregationStrategy'. I guess in my case, the timer which is getting fired at 1 second is resetting the imap exchange body to null in the absence of an aggregation strategy

I am having serious doubts if my design is making sense:
A timer to keep triggering an event to a configuration bean which in turn sets the latest values for the imap url/port to be built dynamically through a pollEnrich which itself has a timeout configured.
I agree the timeout can be toyed with finding a 'sweet-spot' where the folder does not close before the processing is over but there is no certainty of a 'FolderClosedException' to re-occur. Marrying up a scheduler to an event driven bean and that in turn to another poll, doesn't sound good.

@Raphi1, Or a Java based DSL to pick up the IMAP URL/Port from the email config and then build the route over it as you suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78981960/apache-camel-the-mail-message-does-not-have-any-recipients-set/78989585#78989585 could be an answer?

What exactly do you want to achieve? If you don't want to close the folder, you can set closeFolder=false. You would need the AggregationStrategy to get access to your 'old' exchange (the connection data) AND the 'new' exchange (your email data) for further processing and creating a result exchange.

Thank you @Raphi1 ; Lemme try that closeFolder=false. I'll post the design question in a separate post just to have a peer review
